# ng2-bootstrap can't find angular-cli.json file to input styles array

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, ng2-bootstrap

I can't complete the last step to enable bootstrap in my Angular 2 application because I don't have the angular-cli.json file anywhere?

I'm following this tutorial:
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/blob/development/docs/getting-started/ng-cli.md

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: if you used the correct version of angular-cli, this file definitely exists.

Comment: I downloaded an example from here and modified it to use in my application. Maybe that's why I don't have that file? http://angular2-first-look.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: The "tutorial" you linked is the quickstart to use when using `ng2-bootstrap` with a project built with `angular-cli`.  `Angular-cli` is a installer/configurer/packager for angular2, and the current version of this package uses `webpack`.  This is only one possible way to manage packages for angular2;  the example from your comments appears to be a modified version of the angular seed, which uses `systemjs`.  You might try the other instructions for `ng-2bootstrap`, related to angular seed:  https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/blob/development/docs/getting-started/angular-seed.md

Answer (score 0):

Try a smaller angular2 seed. Here's mine. It includes bootstrap 3 without ng2-bootstrap. But you can easy change it by adding this in "dependencies" in the package.json

```
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.18",
"bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6"
```

In app.module

```
import {NgbModule} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes, {useHash: true}),
        SettingsModule,
        NgbModule.forRoot()
    ],
```

and in the example settings modules (and other modules) you need to import it:

```
import {NgbModule} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
imports: [BrowserModule,NgbModule,HttpModule,FormsModule],
```

[Minimum angular2 seed](https://github.com/Jensiator/minimal-angular2-webpack-seed)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! But now I'm getting a 404 error:
GET http://localhost:3000/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap 404 (Not Found)

What am I doing wrong? And why is it such a hassle to get the Bootstrap framework working in Angular 2? I thought it would work out of the box?

Comment: I just got everything 'working', no errors anymore. I had to add the file location to system.js.config.js. But my html is not styled?

Comment: As you see in my seed I'm not using system.js so I cant help you with that. In my seed I'm using webpack. I choose webpack because its more mature. One day I might switch to system.js but not now. ng-bootstrap is still in alpha and uses bootstrap4 which is also in alpha. So don't expect everything to work out of the box

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I started a new angular cli project and put all the files in there and now I got everything working and I have all the correct files now! No idea what went wrong...